# Why is the focus owner in a Java Swing applicaton using Cardlayout null?

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a game with multiple screens (loading, menu, playing, credits). This is implemented by using different JPanels for each GameState. I was first using a KeyListener which was added to every Panel but that was very buggy and doesn't seem to be the best way. Therefore I decided to use KeyBindings for the first time. After having read the documentation I wrote for every GameState KeyBindings like this:

```
panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "START");
panel.getActionMap().put("START", new SwitchStateAction(gameStateManager, "PLAYING"));
```

This only worked for the first panel, so after pressing a key, the panel was switched. Then pressing a key wouldn't work. After reading more about KeyBindings I learned that there are different input maps.
Everyone seemed to suggest to use WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW. This seems to solve the problem altough I don't understand why.
I provide a minimal reproducable example of my problem here:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().createAndShowGUI();
                
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        //trace focus owner
        new Timer(1000/2, e -> update()).start();
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel1.add(new JButton("I do nothing panel 1"));
        panel1.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("2"), "2");
        panel1.getActionMap().put("2", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) panel.getLayout();
                cl.show(panel, "panel2");
            }
        });
        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2.add(new JButton("I do nothing panel 2"));
        panel2.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("1"), "1");
        panel2.getActionMap().put("1", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) panel.getLayout();
                cl.show(panel, "panel1");
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(panel1, "panel1");
        panel.add(panel2, "panel2");
        
        frame.add(panel);
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) panel.getLayout();
        cl.show(panel, "panel1");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    private void update() {
        Component c = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
//      System.out.println("Focus-Owner: " + ((c == null) ? "null" : c.getName()));
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

With this code I discovered that altough it seems to work to transition back and forth, the focus owner gets null after switching panels. Still it seems to work. But if the focus owner is null and an event travels to all the components within the focused component (when using WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW) as the documentation says, how does it start since the focus owner is null?!
I would be very gratefull if someone might help me to understand how this works.
Thank you

Comment: WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW means exactly what it says.  It doesn’t care whether there’s a focus owner.  It only cares whether the window itself is the focused window (that is, foreground window) on the desktop.

Comment: @VGR So first, it is possible that there is no focus owner at a time?! And second I understood the documentation article about Key Binding so that different input maps are searched in a special order which starts to look through the input maps of the focus component, then ancestors and then the window comps. But how does it do that when there is no component to have focus and thefore start this chain of looking through the maps?

Comment: “it is possible that there is no focus owner at a time?”  Yes.  See [Window.getFocusOwner()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#getFocusOwner()) and [KeyboardFocusManager.getFocusOwner()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getFocusOwner()).  “how does it do that when there is no component to have focus”  The focused component and the focused window are two different conditions.  There can still be a focused window even when no component has focus.